# StackOverflowError in VS2015 whilst using GridView without paging

Tags: c#, gridview, visual-studio-2015, stack-overflow

I am experiencing strange behaviour in VS2015 whilst debugging. There is a `GridView` with 300 records and a `CheckBox` to choose which record to print.

If the `GridView` is left without paging, so I can view all the records, Visual Studio breaks with a `StackOverflowError`.

This doesn't happen if I am paging the `GridView` or if I manage less than 50 records.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: You should add your code to your question and the exact error-message.

Comment: The error is: System.StackOverflowException in mscorlib.dll. And the debug ending.
The code is simple:

Comment: The code is simple: 

void BindData()
{
IEnumerable<Planning> data = new Planning().GetPlanning();

// Code to filtering data... All the planning event in a month ~ 300 records

gridview1.DataSource = data;
gridview1.DataBind();
}